# Is there a cross-browser way I can fire an event after printing using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I need to be able to print a jQuery UI dialog. My solution thus far has led me to create a "Print" button that creates a new `<iframe>` filled with the contents of the dialog and then prints it.

I'd like to be able to remove the `<iframe>` as soon as the printing has completed. Is there any way I can do this? I know there is an `onAfterPrint` event in IE, but I need this to work in all browsers.

**Edit:** I appreciate the alternative suggestions, however I ran into all kinds of problems trying to use CSS rules to print jQuery dialogs. On pages with a lot of content and multiple dialogs, the structure of the overlay and other elements would cause extra blank pages to be printed. I've tried many combinations of `{ visibility: hidden; }` and `{ display: none; }` but couldn't find a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered making a special stylesheet with the media="print" attribute? Make this stylesheet hide everything else on the page that you don't want to print and reset any formatting as needed. (For example, reset the positioning on the box from absolute to static)

Comment: Although this doesn't answer what was asked, I think it is a fair solution to the core problem of the asker. +1

Comment: A far more practical idea than the OP asked for; +1

Comment: I use this method for normal pages without dialogs, however I didn't think it would be possible to use CSS to print only the top most dialog with proper formatting. There are quite a few situations where there will be multiple dialogs on the screen and only the top most, or the one with focus, should be printed.

Comment: Ended up moving things around to make it work with CSS. Definitely worth the time invested in the restructuring in order to achieve a much cleaner solution.

Comment: This is brilliant - I keep forgetting about these media queries! MUCH simpler and more flexible